# undefined method `start=' gcal4ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use gcal4ruby to add an event to a google calendar. When I run my code, I get this error:

```
undefined method `start=' for #<GCal4Ruby::Event:0x00000102bb47b8>
```

Here's my code:

```
service = GCal4Ruby::Service.new
service.authenticate("username", "password")
cal = GCal4Ruby::Calendar.find(service, "calendarname", :first)
event = GCal4Ruby::Event.new(cal)
event.title = "Soccer Game"
event.start = Time.parse("12-06-2009 at 12:30 PM")
event.end = Time.parse("12-06-2009 at 1:30 PM")
event.where = "Merry Playfields"
event.save
```

The error occurs on the line "event.start = ..."

This is confusing me because this code is literally copied from the documentation.

EDIT: After opening up the actual .rb files of the plugin, it turns out the documentation is simply wrong. the methods event.start and event.end should be event.start_time and event.end_time. But now I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `editable' for nil:NilClass
```

At the "event.save" line. Anyone work with this plugin and have a clue? Or can suggest a library for working with google calendar that has better documentation? ;-)

Comment: this one? https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the event assignment to

```
event = GCal4Ruby::Event.new(service)
```

If that doesn't work I'd do a `gem which gcal4ruby` (or whatever the name of the gem is) and look at the code there. Because according to the [source code](https://github.com/mgornick/gcal4ruby/blob/master/lib/gcal4ruby/event.rb#L136) the `start` method definitely exists.

Comment: thanks for this tip! haven't solved it yet, but I'm getting closer (updated original post)

Comment: I accepted your answer because I ended up using the plugin you suggested instead of gcal4ruby

Answer (score 2):

I was actually stuck with the same error. Both your edit and Dty's answer helped me figure this out. This was my solution.

```
event = Event.new(service, {
    :calendar => cal, 
    :title => "Event on "+s.start_date.strftime('%D'), 
    :start_time => s.start_date, 
    :end_time => s.end_date, 
    :where => "www.example.com"})

event.save
```